# How to verify whether a shortcut-keysequence is valid?

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts

In my application I allow the user to enter shortcuts in a line-edit.  E.g., if the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, this means that a certain action will be executed if the user presses <kbd>F10</kbd>.

I use the QKeySequence class to convert the string <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to a QKeySequence, and then pass this QKeySequence to the QShortCut's constructor.

Is there a way to verify that the QKeySequence is valid for a shortcut?  E.g. if the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, this is converted to a QKeySequence, but I don't want to allow this for a shortcut.
Same with strings like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (which becomes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), ...

Comment: If noone else proposes a better solution, you could use regular expressions (QRegExp) to validate your input before you pass it to a QKeySequence

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim.  In the mean time I found out that I have to use the count method of the QKeySequence to check whether the key sequence refers to one key, then the [] operator of QKeySequence to get the first (single) key, and then compare it using the Qt::Key enum and Qt::KeyboardModifier values.  It's a bit hacking (so I'm still hoping for a better way).

Comment: That's pretty much it. Arguably the constructor should throw if it can't construct a valid key sequence, but the designers opted to make it a non-throwing library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prevent the user from entering himself the shortcut text, and capture the key directly (you would still have to filter "orphan" modifier keys manually).

See [How can I capture QKeySequence from QKeyEvent depending on current keyboard layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647970/how-can-i-capture-qkeysequence-from-qkeyevent-depending-on-current-keyboard-layou/6665017#6665017) for a working example.

Comment: Good idea.  Although we won't implement this in the short term, I consider this for future developments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled on same question now, and after having debugged into the qkeysequence.cpp you can check the keys to be not Qt::Key_unknown (at least using 5.6.3...):

```
auto shortcut = QKeySequence("Ctrl+F10+Ctrl");
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  if(shortcut[i] == Qt::Key_unknown)
    // QKeySequence not parsed correctly, handle properly
```