# How to create a hotkey field in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qlineedit

What is the easiest way to allow user to input a key combination? 
It would basically look like `QLineEdit` field but it would accept key combinations only.

For example, there is something already in the Qt Designer where you can assign a shortcut for an Action. My requirement is exactly the same. TIA

[image: Edit Action - assigning a shortcut]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Qt 5.2 onwards, you can use [QKeySequenceEdit](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qkeysequenceedit.html) for this purpose

Comment: Link should be updated to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator is actually open source.  So if you want exactly what that dialog does, you can peek in and see how they do it.

The implementation of that *"Edit Action"* dialog is in a library called "QtTools".  Here's the header and the source file:

[actioneditor_p.h](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qttools/blobs/master/src/designer/src/lib/shared/actioneditor_p.h)

[actioneditor.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qttools/blobs/master/src/designer/src/lib/shared/actioneditor.cpp)

...but it looks to be a bit indirect, and bootstrapped onto the form engine itself.  You'd have to dig a while to get to the part where it actually captures the key sequence.  Casual browsing sans debugger suggests it is `QtKeySequenceEdit` implemented in these files:

[qtpropertybrowserutils_p.h](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qttools/blobs/master/src/shared/qtpropertybrowser/qtpropertybrowserutils_p.h)

[qtpropertybrowserutils.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qttools/blobs/master/src/shared/qtpropertybrowser/qtpropertybrowserutils.cpp)

Comment: I achieved what I wanted, added as the answer. Thanks again for the proper guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few alternative ways to achieve my requirement. I want a `QLineEdit` like input field, which will capture key combinations that adhere to following formats:

- Alt+Ctrl+Shift+X
- Alt+Ctrl+X
- Alt+Shift+X
- Ctrl+Shift+X

The easiest way to do this is by sub-classing `QLineEdit`& re-implementing `keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * event )` function. My header file and cpp file look like this. Anyone can manipulate the logic inside `keyPressEvent` to suit their requirement.

**QLineEditHotKey.h**

```
#include <QLineEdit>

class QLineEditHotKey: public QLineEdit
{
public:
    QLineEditHotKey( QWidget* pParent = NULL);
    ~QLineEditHotKey(){}
protected:
    void keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event );
};
```

**QLineEditHotKey.cpp**

```
QLineEditHotKey::QLineEditHotKey(QWidget* pParent):QLineEdit(pParent)
{
}

void QLineEditHotKey::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * event )
{
    int keyInt = event->key(); 
    Qt::Key key = static_cast<Qt::Key>(keyInt); 

    // Handle unknown keys
    if( key == Qt::Key_unknown ) 
        return; 

    // Pressing Esc or Backspace will clear the content
    if( key == Qt::Key_Escape || key == Qt::Key_Backspace )
    {  
        setText(NULL);
        return;
    } 

    // Empty means a special key like F5, Delete, Home etc
    if( event->text().isEmpty() )
        return;

    // Checking for key combinations
    Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers = event->modifiers(); 

    if(modifiers.testFlag(Qt::NoModifier)) 
        return;
    if(modifiers.testFlag(Qt::ShiftModifier)) 
        keyInt += Qt::SHIFT; 
    if(modifiers.testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier)) 
        keyInt += Qt::CTRL; 
    if(modifiers.testFlag(Qt::AltModifier)) 
        keyInt += Qt::ALT; 

    setText( QKeySequence(keyInt).toString(QKeySequence::NativeText) );
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647970/how-can-i-capture-qkeysequence-from-qkeyevent-depending-on-current-keyboard-layo) question was very helpful in finding the solution.