# Input for key mapping

Tags: qt, keyboard

To make my application more flexible to user I want to add possibility user to chose Hot keys for some actions in app.
To do this I'll gooing to make some page on settings window.
where Action name and input(QLineEdit) where keys will be desplayd like
Quit |Alt+Q|
What was the best way to capture such Hot Keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start with, you can [setShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qaction.html#shortcut-prop) for your QAction, which will do exactly what you want (trigger QAction, when user hit sequence), example:

```
myAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Backspace));
```

for more details, look up documentation of [QKeySequence class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qkeysequence.html)

EDIT: to grab the sequence itself, look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665017/1741118 . This answer should work. You can derive from widgets, where you would enter sequence, override `QKeyPressEvent` there or just set `QEventFilter` on every widget, that you want to capture events for key sequence

Comment: thx for a piece of advice. But main question for me is how to get  QKeySequence from QKeyPressEvent