# Propagate keyEvent from widget to QKeySequenceEdit

Tags: qt, qkeyevent, qkeysequence

I have a `QTreeWidget` and `QKeySequenceEdit` and I want pressing shortcuts in `QTreeWidget` lead to editing shortcut in `QKeySequenceEdit`. I've installed eventFilter and constructed the corresponding `QShortcut` using this solution:

[How can I capture QKeySequence from QKeyEvent depending on current keyboard layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647970/how-can-i-capture-qkeysequence-from-qkeyevent-depending-on-current-keyboard-layo)

But I'm stuck at sending event to `QKeySequenceEdit`. Here is a piece of code in eventFilter

```
qDebug()<<QKeySequence(keyInt).toString();
QShortcutEvent *shortcutEvent = new QShortcutEvent(QKeySequence(keyInt), QShortcut(QKeySequence(keyInt), this).id());
qApp->postEvent(ui->keySequenceEdit, shortcutEvent);
return true;
```

`qDebug` outputs right keys, but `QKeySequenceEdit` does not react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QKeySequenceEdit::setKeySequence](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html#keySequence-prop).